# How to merge this 2 SQLs

Tags: mysql, sql

How to marge these 2 SQLs

```
UPDATE images SET Appear = Appear + 1 WHERE  image_hub = X
```

```
SELECT images.Image_branch FROM animals INNER JOIN Images ON animals.ID = Images.Image_hub WHERE animals.id = 1;
```

I want to use the result of SQL:B for SQL:A as X.
How to marge this 2 sqls.

Comment: Merging an `UPDATE`  and a `SELECT`  query does not make any sense. What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE images 
SET Appear = Appear + 1 
WHERE image_hub = (
    SELECT images.Image_branch 
    FROM animals 
    INNER JOIN Images ON animals.ID = Images.Image_hub 
    WHERE animals.id = 1
);
```

I think that's what you want to do